# Bluetooth COM port reading garbage data

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, hyperterminal

I have a bluetooth device which communicates with a system and I want to enhance that system. I tried adding the bluetooth device to my computer and started sending some information from bluetooth device to my computer and in computer with the help of hyperterminal I tried to read the data from COM5 port but the data looks like the below

Can anyone tell me why I cannot read the correct data on hyperterminal? Thanks.

[image]

Current settings are bits/sec:9200  data bits:8 parity:none stop bits:1 flow control none.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error caused due to wrong baud rate.Changing the baud rate could work.